# jQuery toggle height from x to x

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, toggle

I'd like to toggle a height of a div from a specific height (abcHeight) to auto. Is this possible? I've tried this:

```
let abcHeight = $('.abc').height();

$('.def').css('height', abcHeight);
$('.def').animate({height: 'toggle', opacity: 1}, 5000);
```

PS: height of .def should be as height as the content inside (= auto).

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to add **"px"** or **"%"** after `abcHeight`.

This will do for you:

```
let abcHeight = $('.abc').height();

$('.def').css('height', abcHeight+"px");
$('.def').animate({height: 'toggle', opacity: 1}, 5000);
```